# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal -Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting `SyntaxError:` EOL while scanning string literal in this part.

```
system.cpu.workload = LiveProcess(cmd = 'hello’, executable ='hello')
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7):

Problem is you're using different types of quotes around `hello`(`cmd = 'hello’`). One on the left is ASCII single quote and other one is `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`.

```
>>> 'hello’
  File "<ipython-input-56-3231cc2cf7bf>", line 1
    'hello’
            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

>>> 'hello'
'hello'
```

`’` is actually a [unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode):

```
>>> "’".decode('utf-8')
u'\u2019'
```

Answer (score 2):

Right quote surrounding "hello" is wrong - it is backquote, instead of plain one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a wrong single quote in your code.  There are three kinds of quotes in Python:

```
" double quote
' single quote
` backtick
```

Double quotes and single quotes are used interchangeably; use the one kind if the value contains the other to avoid ugly escape sequences using backslashes.

Backticks, however, are more like an operator and convert the value enclosed by them into its "string representation".

It looks to me as if you mixed single quotes and a backtick in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a multiline string with **'...'**. You have to use **''' ... '''** or **""" ... """**.