# How do I fix the EOL Syntax error in this programm

Tags: python

[I tried running this program that I made but it kept having the message "SyntaxError, EOL while scanning string literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4hzq.png)

import random
import math

def RoTMG_HP_Function () :
    initial = 0
    for x in range (19) :
        initial +=  (random.randint(-5, 5))
    return initial

'''print(RoTMG_HP_Function())'''

def Roll_Simulator(x):
    x = int(input("enter number of simulations."))
    RollsList = []
    for i in range (x):
        RollsList.append(str(RoTMG_HP_Function()))

```
'''#Miscellaneous code, just test case, not relevant
for i in range (-95,96):
    Listcount = 0
    for j in range (200):
        if int(Rollslist[j]) == i:
            Listcount +=1
    if Listcount > 0:
        print('The roll of ' + str(i) + ' appears ' + str(Listcount) + ' times. ')''''
LifepotExpenditure = 0
for i in range (-19,20):
    Listcount = 0
    RollsLower = 0
    for j in range (x):
        if math.floor(int(RollsList[j]) // 5) == i:
            Listcount +=1
        elif math.floor(int(RollsList[j]) // 5) < i:
            RollsLower += 1
    if Listcount > 0:
        print('Differential of ' + str(i) + ': ' + str(Listcount) + '. The probability of this is ' + str(float(100*Listcount / x)) + '%. The probability of a worse roll is ' + str(float(100*RollsLower / x)) + '%.')
    LifepotExpenditure += i*(Listcount)
AverageLifepotExpenditure = float(19.0) - float(LifepotExpenditure / x)
print('\n' + 'On average, you will spend ' + str(AverageLifepotExpenditure) + ' lifepots to max life.')
```

print(Roll_Simulator(21))

Comment: Please copy the code and paste here

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21089462/3562607. Hard to tell from the image (you should paste your code within a code block or share it via other means). Scan your code and make sure all the quotes are correct.

Comment: Maybe you could use http://pastebin.com/ but looking by your image it should've been accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
print('The roll of ' + str(i) + ' appears ' + str(Listcount) + ' times. ')''''
```

Has one extra comma in the end, just remove it

Comment: Ohhh, Thank you very much

Comment: One more thing off topic @J.Martin, it seems to me that you're starting some python development. I recommend using other text editors like Sublime Text, Atom or Notepad++ (Google it later, they're very helpful!)